# ¿Por que if isset() de php no funciona al momento de enviar datos por ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Hola a todos eh estado practicando con php y ajax para el envio de datos resulta que eh creado dos formularios

```
 <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" value="datos del formulario 1" name="datosForm1">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>

    <form id="form2">
        <input type="text" value="datos del formulario 2" name="datosForm2">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
```

Y con ajax envio los datos de los dos forms estos son independientes

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form1").on("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: new FormData(this), 
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    console.log("error: " + jqXHR + textStatus);
                });
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form2").on("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: new FormData(this), 
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    console.log("error: " + jqXHR + textStatus);
                });
        });
    });
```

Mientras que en php tengo

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['datosForm1'])) {
    echo "aqui vendrian los datos del form1";
}


if (isset($_POST['datosForm2'])) {
    echo "aqui vendrian los datos del form2";
}

?>
```

El caso es que al hacer submit al segundo form no recibe los datos en `(isset($_POST['datosForm2'])` es decir no hace la validacion para solo recibir los datos del segundo formulario si no que las dos condicionales se activan y ambas reciben los datos. ¿Cual podria ser el problema?

Comment: Has probado ver que recibes al enviar un formulario? puedes hacer un var_dump para ver que datos estas recibiendo al inicio del archivo y verlo desde el inspector de elementos

Comment: recibe el dato que deberia

Comment: Vale, prueba colocando las condiciones dentro del var_dump ambas para ver si te sale true o false, var_dump(isset($_POST['datosForm1']), isset($_POST['datosForm2']))

Comment: Intenta añadiendo el method ="post" en el html del formulario

Comment: ¿Qué muestra exactamente un `var_dump($_POST);`?